# jquery ui - when resizing a floating div horizontally, the height is also modified

Tags: jquery, html, resizable

I have a bit of code where clicking on a grid creates a DIV, with position absolute, a fixed height of 8px, and a bottom, left and width set. 
I use jquery UI to implement dragging and resizing (I have included the CSS file and the jquery-ui js file.

I have set resize handles to "w, e" so it can only be resized horizontally. That works fine, but the bottom and height are changed, because after three times resizing the div is as small as 2px. It seems to lose 2px per 'resize session'.

I used http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/ as example, where it works fine. So what is going wrong here?

some code (simplified):

```
var left = 200;
var width = 120;
var invertedRowIndex = 8; // calculated in real code
var ROW_HEIGHT = 17;
var jqo = $("div.grid");
var bottom = (invertedRowIndex * ROW_HEIGHT) + "px";
var html = "<div class=\"mybar\" id=\"bar1\" style=\"left: " + left + "px; bottom: " + bottom + "; width: " + width + "px\"><!-- fill --></div>";
jqo.append(html);
var jq = $("div#bar1").addClass("cursor-pointer");
jq.resizable({
        handles: "w, e",
        grid: [10, 10],
        minHeight: 8,
        maxHeight: 8,
        minWidth: 10
    });
```

Comment: could  you possibly provide a link to the page or create an example on jsFiddle?

Comment: hmm... I started from scratch and now cannot reproduce the problem in the simple test, it works perfectly. It then probably is caused because of the jquery resizable div is positioned within an Ext-js4 grid component, which has a table (although that doesn't cause the problem in my little test), where the floating div is a direct child of the DIV hosting the grid itself. I need that Ext-js component though since it is required in my project. So I will need to find a way to solve this...

Comment: you could try to reset the height of the element inside the `stop` event of resizable

Comment: I tried that (also resetting the height in the resize event) and it works. It may not be the nicest way to fix it, but if it works good enough, no problem.

Comment: what also seems to work is setting the !important flag to the height option in CSS. After adding that and removing the events, the height of the div also remained intact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this the way Andy mentioned in a comment:

"you could try to reset the height of the element inside the stop event of resizable"